# How to generate Doxygen documents from DSL language

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, doxygen, doxygen-wizard, doxygen-addtogroup

I want to generate Doxygen document for my DSL(Domain Specific Language). As my DSL language is totally different from C,C++,Java languages.

Basically mine is eclipse plugin project and we are developing IDE for DSL language in that i want to generate Doxygen out of DSL project.

I am very new to Doxygen topic. Please let me know some ideas to proceed.

Note: I have added dependencies so i could generate Doxygen document for Java. The thing i don't know how to do it for my DSL language.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it is not possible without hacks. You have three options

- Either you add support for your DSL to doxygen and recompile it
- Use the INPUT_FILTER option. This will probably fail if your DSL is not an imperative OOP language like Java and C++, because trouble in concept translation.
- Do not use doxygen, but another tool which is easier to extend.

If I knew about another tool I would have recommended the third option.

Comment: Hi, I am very sorry. Still i didn't get answer for my question. Please anybody can you help me.

Comment: @Saran Doxygen does not support custom Domain Specific Languages.

Comment: Yes so that i can generate either c/java file related to my DSL language from that i can able to generate Doxygen?

Comment: @Saran This is the hacky way. You can use the INPUT_FILTER option and Doxygen will run your converter program. But this solution has many limitations. For example, if your DSL is data flow driven, then you are probably out of luck.